# Error in installing r packages through python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, package, rpy2

I have managed to install `rpy2` on python 3.5.2, and my R version is 3.3.2, working on windows7. I am trying to install a package in r through `rpy2` and there is an error that I cannot understand how to solve. Here is the code I typed in the iPython console:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R install.packages("devtools")
```

When I do that, a pop-up window comes up, asking "Would you like to use a personal library instead?". If I say yes, then I get the error:

```
Error in install.packages("devtools") : 
unable to create 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\external\'
```

and if I say no, then the error is:

```
Error in install.packages("devtools") : unable to install packages
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a permissions error that can be solved by using `sudo`?

Comment: I am unsure of this. Can you please propose how it could be solved using `sudo`?

Comment: If you are installing through the terminal, then prepend `sudo` to your command. e.g. `pip install rpy2` fails due to permission error, then use `sudo pip install rpy2` instead (given that you have sudo user permission).

Comment: But the problem is not with installing `rpy2`. That is installed. The problem is in installing r packages via the ipython console

Comment: My bad, you seem to be on windows.

Comment: Yes I am on windows, I will add that to the question.